# How to extract Date Info from within a text using c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

So the problem is i am writing a code which detect all the American Addresses within a text. I come across the problem that cases like 10.08.2013 can potentially be house numbers since in my algorithm i simply use isdigit() to look for numbers and those which have less than 5 digits get marked as house numbers.
Is there any way to exclude such digits not to be mistaken for house numbers?

Comment: Why do you have American Addresses mixed up with German dates?

Comment: Just look for separators around the numbers.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes It doesnt really matter how the date is formatted the important point is how to differentiate them from numbers.

Comment: @FERY Oh why, the date format is pretty much *everything* that matters. If you don't know how the date is formatted, your task is impossible.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Actually i am doing this task for so many other countries too. i didnt really pay attention when posting this question because it was not relevant to this particular question

Comment: @Gorpik it is a good idea but most of the time a sentence within a text starts with a house number like : " and then we walk back home. 700 king Road OH 12345 was his place's address." in such cases looking for separators wouldn't work either

Comment: So you mean that house numbers will always be preceded and followed by blanks, while numbers in dates will always be preceded or followed by a non-blank? Then it is easy.

Comment: @Gorpik **10.01.2013 West Market Street OH 35611** i want cases like this not to be marked as an address

Comment: So if you find a string of soemthing that starts and end with digits, but does contain non-digits? I think you need to care for 221B Baker Street tho', so the last digit may be a letter. And apparently (according to wikipedia (here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_numbering), in parts of New York, the house number is indeed 65-12 - the twelth property on the 65th block). Not sure if there is an easy way to solve this problem.

Comment: Nice. `10` is followed by a `.`, `01` is both preceded and followed by a `.`, `2013` is preceded by a `.`, `35611` is preceded and followed by blanks. This meets the conditions I set. Now, the cases exposed by @MatsPetersson are indeed harder.

Comment: is the date format always mm.dd.yyyy? If so, why not just pattern match that? Are you likely to get a house number with that format? If you did you could filter on a valid date. But if you get a house number in a format mm.dd.yyyy that is also a valid date I think you're stuck without some kind of contextual parsing of the string.

Comment: `cases like 10.08.2013 can potentially be house numbers` Strange house numbers.

Comment: @FERY: I suggest that you begin to "pay attention" _before_ asking the internet for free help.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i suggest u calm down before u get all sarcastic about everything. 10.08.2013 is not a house number even a monkey knows that.but since isdigit() function would return TRUE if it was checking it without any intelligent algorithms we wish to figure out a way to exclude it!

Comment: @FERY: Without programming, your computer is not as intelligent as a monkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pattern match using *Regular Expressions*. You can learn about how to use regular expressions with C++ [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/).

So for each line that you retrieve from the file, or however you may be gathering that data, you can check it against a pattern to determine if it is a date.

[This](http://cpprocks.com/wp-content/uploads/c++11-regex-cheatsheet.pdf) is also a good reference.

This should be roughly what you are looking for: `".^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}$."`